# Align the characters in div one below the other (vertical align)

Tags: jquery, css, vertical-text

I would like to vertically align the text in div on the click on a button.

I am using php and jquery framework library.

This is what I am trying to ask:

Ex: "myname is xyz" (normal alignment)

Vertical alignment

```
Ex:
m
y

n
a
m
e
....
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word-wrap property of css

```
 <script>
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").html($("div").html().split(" ").join("&nbsp;"));
    if($("div").width()==1)
    {
    $("div").width("100%");
    }
    else
    {$("div").width(1);
    }
    });</script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bkkK6/21/)

Comment: this is a clever solution. But why are you setting height? What about spaces between words?

Comment: I would like to toggle it to normal txt on button clicks.

Comment: <div id="draggable1" class="draggable1" style="word-wrap:break-word;">ggg</div> var $options = $('#draggable1').text(); I am unable to get the div text into $options.

Comment: Object my name has no method 'width'

Comment: try asking a new question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

There are several possibilities for making stuff like this. One of the easiest approaches would be to insert a `<br>` tag after each letter...

HTML:

```
<div>foo bar</div>
<button>button</button>
```

JS:

```
var state, $div = $('div');
$('button').click(function(){
    if (!state) {
        $div.html($div.html().split('').join('<br>'));
        state = true;
    } else {
        $div.html($div.html().split('<br>').join(''));
        state = false;
    }
});
```

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/bkkK6/22/

Edit:

split/join if you like it more ... :D

Comment: how can I toggle between normal text and vertical text on button click?

Comment: check out: http://jsfiddle.net/bkkK6/10/ ... this does what you want although it could be coded cleaner ;)

Comment: @roasted i see your fiddle but if i will replace space with nbsp then that will also become inefficient even more than than this answer

Comment: @conceptdeluxe using split and join function will reduce your code size by 80%

Comment: @roasted no that wold be efficient because you were inserting space between words but this is inserting space blindly between letters

Comment: @ankit can you give us a demo code using split and join function.

Comment: @Fakhruddin Ujjainwala ... here it is